# Elasticsearch "serialization message unable to parse/serialize body"

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I'm creating a single HTML page that displays a summary.  I've got four other queries and I've had no issues.  But, I would like to display the recovery status when there's an issue and I'm getting an error.  Once I get this query working, I'll pull out what I need and display it in a table.  But, for now my basic code is below:

```
function showRecovery(){
   client.cat.recovery().then(function (resp)   {
      console.log("Recovery status is:\n", resp);
    });
}
```

It returns error "Uncaught (in promise)" and this message:

Serialization {message: "Unable to parse/serialize body",...